# concat string without "exit" from the string

Tags: java, string, sqlite, concatenation

i use java from a lot of time but i never found a better "graphical" way for concat strings, when i write SQL query i have a hard to read query for all the concats i made (i use a java class for the name values of all the columns of the db) something like

```
public static class DBMetaData {

static class LISTINO_TABLE {
    static final String TABLE_NAME = "listino";
    static final String ID = "_ID";
    static final String PRODUCT_NAME_KEY = "nome_prodotto";
    static final String CODE_KEY = "codice";
    static final String PRICE_KEY = "prezzo";
    static final String ENABLE_KEY = "enable";
    static final String PREZZO_VENDITA_KEY = "prezzo_vendita";
    static final String RICAVO_KEY = "ricavo";
    static final String NUMERO_COLLI_KEY = "num_colli";
    static final String TIPO_COLLO_KEY = "tipo_collo";
    static final String DATA_INSERIMENTO_KEY = "data_inserimento";
}
```

and when i write the query i have query like that

```
    String sql = "select *,lo." + DBMetaData.LISTINO_ORDINE_TABLE.QUANTITY_KEY + " as quant from " + DBMetaData.LISTINO_ORDINE_TABLE.TABLE_NAME +
            " lo left join "+DBMetaData.OFFERTE_TABLE.TABLE_NAME + " o on lo."+ DBMetaData.LISTINO_ORDINE_TABLE.CODICE_ID + " = o." + DBMetaData.OFFERTE_TABLE.CODICE_ARTICOLO_KEY +
            " left join "+DBMetaData.LISTINO_TABLE.TABLE_NAME + " l on lo."+DBMetaData.LISTINO_ORDINE_TABLE.CODICE_ID + "= l."+DBMetaData.LISTINO_TABLE.CODE_KEY +
            " left join " + DBMetaData.INVENTARIO_TABLE.TABLE_NAME + " i on lo."+DBMetaData.LISTINO_ORDINE_TABLE.CODICE_ID + "= i."+DBMetaData.INVENTARIO_TABLE.CODE_KEY +
            " where "+DBMetaData.LISTINO_ORDINE_TABLE.NUMBER_KEY + " = 0 order by "+DBMetaData.LISTINO_ORDINE_TABLE.QUANTITY_KEY + " DESC";
```

there is a better way for write the query? i know i can just write the query without use my DBMetaData, but if i wanna edit in the future something i have to re-edit all my sqls and the use of the class is a practice i learnt when i started with android and i'm using it but i don't like it :-)

any tips? tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `String.format` to remove the need for all the string concatenation.

For example:

```
String sql = String.format("select * from %s", TABLE_NAME);
```

You could also use Apache Commons Text's [`StringSubstitutor`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html).

```
final Map<String, String> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();
valuesMap.put("tableName", "Table");
//etc...

final String string = "select * from ${tableName}";
final String sql = new StringSubstitutor(valuesMap).replace(string);
//"select * from Table"
```

Comment: Agreed ! This is the shortest we can get.!